# Can 'npm update' use global packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

If I have a Node.js package with a missing `node_modules` folder. Executing the `npm update` command will create and properly populate the `node_modules` folder with all the necessary packages.

What I don't understand is;

1. Why does it include packages which are already present in the global `node_modules` folder?
2. Why will it not create folder links instead?
3. Am I missing a command line parameter?

Thanks!

**Edit**:

1. Running the `npm update -g` command will not solve the problem.
2. I don't know if it is relevant information, but I'd like to solve it in Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Global and local packages are treated differently (rightly so!).

`npm update -g` will update all global packages

This is documented [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-packages-downloaded-from-the-registry).

Comment: I don't understand. If the node_modules folder is missing in my local Node.js application, then running the 'npm update -g' command will not create it.

Comment: No it will not. These are two different things and need to be treated differently. One command for local, another for global.
You can't do both in one "npm update" command.